# jQuery AutoComplete Not Working with JSON Response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON response and I am trying to get autocomplete to work but it is having issues.

**Question:**

Here is my jQuery ajax "success" method to handle the returned JSON string: (I have listed my JSON response below):

**The Code:**

```
success: function( data ) {
    response( $.map( data.productSkus, function( item ) {
        return {
            label: item.product.name + " - " + item.product.sku,
            name: item.product.name,
            value: item.product.sku,
            id: item.product.id,
            product_sku: item.product.sku
        }
    }));
}
```

**The Issue:**

I am sure that the issue why it isn't showing options is because each array element has the **"0": {** before the content of the array. How do I access these? I have tried item[0] but that does not seem to work. I know that this script works, it just broke when I had to do a "group by" in my php code. Once I did the group by it added the **"0": {**. Thanks for your help!

**JSON Response:**

```
{
    "responseCode": 200,
    "responseVal": "Success",
    "productSkus": [
        {
            "0": {
                "id": 16685,
                "qty": 8,
                "reserved_qty": 0,
                "created": {
                    "date": "2014-01-20 17:32:31",
                    "timezone_type": 3,
                    "timezone": "Europe/Paris"
                },
                "updated": null,
                "deletedAt": null,
                "inventoryLocation": {
                    "id": 523,
                    "saleable": true,
                    "name": "M-10A-4",
                    "created": {
                        "date": "2013-04-11 18:46:11",
                        "timezone_type": 3,
                        "timezone": "Europe/Paris"
                    },
                    "updated": {
                        "date": "2013-04-11 18:46:11",
                        "timezone_type": 3,
                        "timezone": "Europe/Paris"
                    },
                    "deletedAt": null,
                    "warehouse": {
                    }
                }
            },
            "name": "Tiger Costume Brown"
        },
        {
            "0": {
                "id": 48917,
                "qty": 0,
                "reserved_qty": 0,
                "created": {
                    "date": "2014-01-20 23:44:15",
                    "timezone_type": 3,
                    "timezone": "Europe/Paris"
                },
                "updated": null,
                "deletedAt": null,
                "inventoryLocation": {
                    "id": 4056,
                    "saleable": true,
                    "name": "W-2E-26R-204",
                    "created": {
                        "date": "2014-01-20 23:30:58",
                        "timezone_type": 3,
                        "timezone": "Europe/Paris"
                    },
                    "updated": null,
                    "deletedAt": null,
                    "warehouse": {
                    }
                }
            },
            "name": "Tiger Costume White"
        }
    ],
    "productsCount": 7
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the literal item['0'] to get that key?

Comment: It should probably be `item[0].name`, `item[0].id` etc

Comment: I just noticed there are 2 objects in your json response and they both are mapped to a single key -- "0". May be that is causing this issue1

Comment: @Ishita those are two separate objects, each with the key "0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would doublecheck this on the phpside and maybe correct it (just take the element under zero and append it directly). If this isnt possible correct it in JS:

```
success: function( data ) {
    response( $.map( data.productSkus, function( item ) {
        if(item[0]){
            item[0].name = item.name
            item = item[0];
        }
        return {
            label: item.name + " - " + item.sku,
            name: item.name,
            value: item.sku,      // Not in the JSON
            id: item.id,
            product_sku: item.sku // Not in the JSON
        }
    }));
}
```

When this isnt working, use typeof instead.

// Edit: Did crap. Corrected it

// Edit: Removed the product-key since it is not present in the JSON

// Edit: Now it nearly fits the json

Comment: There is no property named "product" anywhere in that JSON.

Comment: I didnt check al the properties of the JSON. You re right ofc. Seems like the product should be "0" instead. @LargeTuna: skip the product in your javascript. I will edit my post accordingly

Comment: Still not right... there is no sku and the name is on the same level as the "0". Whats happening here? Pls post your php-code, too

Comment: sorry, my bad, i fixed my JSON

Comment: So this issue is clsoed?

Comment: yes, I added an answer. Wish I could delete the post but I cant.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was actually in my PHP code. Disregard this question all together.

Comment: You can delete your post, or provide a the fix you made for future users with a similar issue.

Comment: Tried to delete it and it said that I cannot because answers were made. Fuzzyma made a valid reponse, I checked Fuzzyma's answer as the correct one.